# Why is the Netlify deploy button missing in CodeSandbox during a React course?

Tags: deployment, netlify, codesandbox

I can't find netlify deploy in codesandbox

I am watching a React online course.
In this course, coding is done on 'CodeSandbox' and deployment is done through 'Netlify'.
However, the CodeSandbox I am using only has buttons for deploying to Vercel and GitHub Pages.
I would like to know the reason for this.

[image: my codesandbox deploy console]

I created accounts using all of my Google emails, but the same issue persists.

I also asked the creator of the online course, and they mentioned that the Netlify deployment button is showing correctly for them, and they cannot identify the cause.